# Tkinter: Scheduling Sequential Threads executed via button clicks

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading

I have a Tkinter GUI with multiple buttons each which call different functions using threads. I have to automate the clicking of the buttons in sequence. So I am using a single <kbd>START</kbd> button, which will click first button, wait for the respective function's execution to complete and then click the next button, and so on.

I used threads as I needed to keep a `Progressbar` running while any function is running.

I am also changing the color of the button text from Red (not run yet) to Blue (being run) to Green (finished execution). I know I need to use `join()` somewhere, but it's not working.

This current code runs all the button `invoke()` methods at once, and not in a sequence.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from threading import Thread
def sample_function():
    for i in range(1,10000) :
        print(i)

def run_function(name, func,btn_variable):
    # Disable all buttons
    btn_variable.configure(style = 'blue.TButton')
    processing_bar.start(interval=10)
    print(name, 'started')
    func()
    processing_bar.stop()
    print(name, 'stopped')
    btn_variable.configure(style = 'green.TButton')

def run_thread(name, func,btn_variable):
    Thread(target=run_function, args=(name, func,btn_variable)).start()


def prepare_clicked():
    run_thread('prepare', sample_function,prepare_btn)
    prepare_btn.configure(style = 'green.TButton')


def social_clicked():
    run_thread('social', sample_function,social_btn)
    social_btn.configure(style = 'green.TButton')


def anomaly_clicked():
    run_thread('anomaly', sample_function,anomaly_btn)
    anomaly_btn.configure(style = 'green.TButton')

def scoring_clicked():
    run_thread('scoring', sample_function,scoring_btn)
    scoring_btn.configure(style = 'green.TButton')

def dashboard_clicked():
    run_thread('dashboard', sample_function,dashboard_btn)
    dashboard_btn.configure(style = 'green.TButton')


def start_all():
    prepare_btn.invoke()
    anomaly_btn.invoke()
    social_btn.invoke()
    scoring_btn.invoke()
    dashboard_btn.invoke()



window = tk.Tk()
#window = tk.Toplevel()

topFrame = tk.Frame(window)
bottomFrame = tk.Frame(window)

# Tell the Frame to fill the whole window
topFrame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
bottomFrame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

# Make the Frame grid contents expand & contract with the window
topFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
for i in range(5):
    topFrame.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

bottomFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
for i in range(3):
    bottomFrame.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

ttk.Style().configure('blue.TButton', foreground='blue')
ttk.Style().configure('green.TButton', foreground='green')
ttk.Style().configure('red.TButton', foreground='red')


prepare_btn = ttk.Button(topFrame, command=prepare_clicked, text='Button 1',style = 'red.TButton')
anomaly_btn = ttk.Button(topFrame,command=anomaly_clicked, text='Button 2',style = 'red.TButton')
social_btn = ttk.Button(topFrame, command=social_clicked, text='Button 3',style = 'red.TButton')
scoring_btn = ttk.Button(topFrame, command=scoring_clicked, text='Button 4',style = 'red.TButton')
dashboard_btn = ttk.Button(topFrame, command=dashboard_clicked, text='Button 5',style = 'red.TButton')
commentary = ttk.Button(bottomFrame,text='START',width=10,command = start_all)
commentarylabel = ttk.Label(bottomFrame,text=' Commentary ',width=25)
processing_bar = ttk.Progressbar(bottomFrame, orient='horizontal', mode='indeterminate')

buttons = [prepare_btn, anomaly_btn, social_btn,scoring_btn,dashboard_btn]


prepare_btn.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='EWNS')
anomaly_btn.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='EWNS')
social_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='EWNS')
scoring_btn.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='EWNS')
dashboard_btn.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='EWNS')
commentary.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='EWNS')
commentarylabel.grid(row=0,column = 1, columnspan=2, sticky='EWNS')
processing_bar.grid(row=0, column=3,columnspan=1, sticky='EWNS')

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `tkinter` doesn't play well with multithreading. That said, it can be done, but only if you restrict yourself to making calls to it in the main thread—a rule that this code does not follow.

Comment: @martineau Ok. How can it be done in a way that the progressbar works indeterminately for each function call ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something to demonstrates how to do what you want. It works because the code running in threads other than the main one don't make it any `tkinter` calls. To get the threads to run sequentially one-after-the-other, it uses a FIFO `Queue` of entries representing each one and starts new ones running when the last one has finished.

To "schedule" a sequence of steps to be run in a certain order as is done in the `start_all()` function, all that needs to be done is to `put()` the information about each one in the order they should be executed in this `job_queue`.

This is all accomplished by repeatedly using the universal [`after()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20190121045017id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method to periodically run a "polling" function (named `poll`) which, among other things, checks to see if another thread is currently executing or not and reacts accordingly.

In the code, the processing each thread does is referred to as either a "step" or a "job".

```
from queue import Queue, Empty
import random
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.messagebox as tkMessageBox
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

random.seed(42)  # Generate repeatable sequence for testing.

ITERATIONS = 100
POLLING_RATE = 100  # millisecs.

# Global variables
cur_thread = None  # Current running thread.
cur_button = None
cur_name = None
job_queue = Queue()  # FIFO queue.

def sample_function():
    for i in range(1, ITERATIONS):
        print(i)
        sleep(0.01)  # Simulate slow I/O.

def start_thread(name, func, btn_variable):
    global cur_thread, cur_button

    if cur_thread is not None:
        tkMessageBox.showerror('Error', "You can't start a step when there"
                                        " are some already running.")
        return

    cur_thread = Thread(target=func)
    cur_button = btn_variable

    btn_variable.configure(style='blue.TButton')
    cur_thread.start()

def poll(window, processing_bar):
    global cur_thread, cur_button

    if cur_thread is not None:
        if cur_thread.is_alive():
            processing_bar.step()
        else:
            cur_thread.join() # Should be immediate.
            cur_thread = None
            processing_bar.stop()
            cur_button.configure(style='green.TButton')
            window.update()
    elif not job_queue.empty():  # More to do?
        try:
            job_info = job_queue.get_nowait()  # Non-blocking.
            start_thread(*job_info)
            processing_bar.start()
            window.update()
        except Empty:  # Just in case (shouldn't happen).
            pass

    window.after(POLLING_RATE, poll, window, processing_bar)

# Button commands.
def prepare_clicked():
    start_thread('prepare', sample_function, prepare_btn)

def social_clicked():
    start_thread('social', sample_function, social_btn)

def anomaly_clicked():
    start_thread('anomaly', sample_function, anomaly_btn)

def scoring_clicked():
    start_thread('scoring', sample_function, scoring_btn)

def dashboard_clicked():
    start_thread('dashboard', sample_function, dashboard_btn)

def start_all():
    global job_queue

    # Put info for each step in the job queue to be run.
    for job_info in (('prepare', sample_function, prepare_btn),
                     ('social', sample_function, social_btn),
                     ('anomaly', sample_function, anomaly_btn),
                     ('scoring', sample_function, scoring_btn),
                     ('dashboard', sample_function, dashboard_btn)):
        job_queue.put(job_info)
    # Start the polling.
    window.after(POLLING_RATE, poll, window, processing_bar)

####
window = tk.Tk()
#window = tk.Toplevel()

topFrame = tk.Frame(window)
bottomFrame = tk.Frame(window)

# Tell the Frame to fill the whole window
topFrame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
bottomFrame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

# Make the Frame grid contents expand & contract with the window
topFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
for i in range(5):
    topFrame.rowconfigure(i, weight=1)

bottomFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
for i in range(3):
    bottomFrame.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)

ttk.Style().configure('blue.TButton', foreground='blue')
ttk.Style().configure('green.TButton', foreground='green')
ttk.Style().configure('red.TButton', foreground='red')

prepare_btn     = ttk.Button(topFrame, command=prepare_clicked, text='Button 1', style='red.TButton')
anomaly_btn     = ttk.Button(topFrame, command=anomaly_clicked, text='Button 2', style='red.TButton')
social_btn      = ttk.Button(topFrame, command=social_clicked, text='Button 3', style='red.TButton')
scoring_btn     = ttk.Button(topFrame, command=scoring_clicked, text='Button 4', style='red.TButton')
dashboard_btn   = ttk.Button(topFrame, command=dashboard_clicked, text='Button 5', style='red.TButton')

commentary      = ttk.Button(bottomFrame, text='START', width=10, command=start_all)
commentarylabel = ttk.Label(bottomFrame, text=' Commentary ', width=25)
processing_bar  = ttk.Progressbar(bottomFrame, orient='horizontal', mode='indeterminate')

prepare_btn.grid    (row=0, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='EWNS')
anomaly_btn.grid    (row=1, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='EWNS')
social_btn.grid     (row=2, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='EWNS')
scoring_btn.grid    (row=3, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='EWNS')
dashboard_btn.grid  (row=4, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='EWNS')

commentary.grid     (row=0, column=0, columnspan=1, sticky='EWNS')
commentarylabel.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky='EWNS')
processing_bar.grid (row=0, column=3,columnspan=1, sticky='EWNS')

window.after(POLLING_RATE, poll, window, processing_bar)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks @martineau That helped!